# why is my VBA code not working

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I got a listbox with numbers in it and a button, i want the listbox to show the number you selected in another form

example i want to buy a number of keys from 1 to 10 if i select 3 i want the next form to show you bought 3 keys

```
Private Sub List28_Click()
If Not IsNull([num of keys]) Then
Forms! [navigation forms].Form.[navigationsubform].Form.User = 
Me.Num_of_keys_Label
Forms! [navigation forms].Form.[navigationsubform].Form.User = Me.List28
End If
DoCmd.Close
EndSub
```

showing the result if a purchase

i get a compile error: invalid use of property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not VBS (Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition). It is VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). VBA is line oriented. If you want to split a long line, you must use a line continuation character preceeded by a space (`_`) at the end of the line.

```
Forms! [navigation forms].Form.[navigationsubform].Form.User = _
    Me.Num_of_keys_Label
```

There should be a space in `EndSub`

```
End Sub
```

Also, indenting the code makes it more readable

```
Private Sub List28_Click()
    If Not IsNull([num of keys]) Then
        Forms![navigation forms].Form.[navigationsubform].Form.User = _
            Me.Num_of_keys_Label
        Forms![navigation forms].Form.[navigationsubform].Form.User = Me.List28
    End If
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

You should use the `AfterUpdate` event. Not the `Click` event. `AfterUpdate` occurs after a new item has been selected.

What is `[num of keys]`? The name of the listbox seems to be `List28`.

`List28` is a bad name. Rename your controls before creating the event methods. This makes the code more readable. E.g. If you rename the listbox to `lstNumbers`, then you get a speaking name for the event method like `lstNumbers_AfterUpdate`. A name like `btnCancel_Click` is easier to understand than `Button17_Click`.

I don't understand the logic of the code. You set the `User` control (a Label or a TextBox?) of the other form to `Me.Num_of_keys_Label` instead of `[num of keys]` which you tested to be not null. Immediately afterwards you replace this value by `Me.List28`, which is, according to your comment (*"the click was for the button"*), a button. This all makes no sense.

Start by prefixing the names of controls and forms. E.g.

`txt` for TextBoxes, e.g. `txtUser`
`btn` for Buttons, e,g, `btnBuy`
`lst` for ListBoxes, e,g, `lstNumOfKeys`
`lbl` for Labels, e,g, `lblResult`
`cbo` for ComboBoxes, e,g, `cboCountry`
`frm` for Forms, e,g, `frmNavigation`
`fsub` for subform controls, e,g, `fsubNavigation`

Comment: num of keys is the list box name

Comment: the click was for the button

Comment: Okay, but then why is the button called `List28`? a better name would be `btnBuy` for the button and `lstNumOfKeys` for the listbox. The current names are misleading. Also, don't use spaces in the names, which then require you to use brackets [ ].

Comment: I changed list 28 to listnumbers